# Postgresql Multiple Database VS Multiple Schemas

Tags: postgresql, schema

We are in the process of building a cluster for our hosted services at work, the final product will be used to host multiple separate services. We are in the middle of deciding on how we want to setup our databases. We are running a postgresql database server which all services in the cluster will use. The debate right now is whether to give each service its own schema in a single database or to give each service its own database.

We just aren't sure which is the better solution for us. None of our services have a common structure and data does not need to be shared. What we are more concerned about is ease of use.

Here's what we care most about, we are really hoping for an objective vs opinion based answer.

Backups

Disaster recovery - all services vs individual

Security between services

Performance

For some additional information, the cluster is hosted within AWS with our database being an RDS instance.

Answer (score 38):

This is what PostgreSQL official docs says:

> Databases are physically separated and access control is managed at the connection level. If one PostgreSQL server instance is to house projects or users that should be separate and for the most part unaware of each other, it is therefore recommendable to put them into separate databases. If the projects or users are interrelated and should be able to use each other's resources they should be put in the same database, but possibly into separate schemas. Schemas are a purely logical structure and who can access what is managed by the privilege system.

Source: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/managing-databases.html

Answer (score 9):

> Disaster recovery - all services vs individual

You can dump and restore one database at a time. You can dump and restore one schema at a time. You can also dump schemas that match a pattern.

> Security between services

I presume you mean isolation between databases and isolation between schemas. The isolation between databases is stronger and more "natural" for developers concerned with "ease of use". For example, if you use one database per service, every developer can just use the public schema for all development.  This might seem "easier" than adding schemas to the search path, or "easier" than using `schema.object` when programming.

It depends in part on how you manage privileges for the roles you use for development, and on how you manage privileges in each database or schema. You can [change default privileges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html).

> Performance

I don't see a measurable difference. YMMV.